# Potentiometers - trimming a potentiometer

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, trim

I'm trying to use two trimpots to set the low and high point of a seperate 16mm pot.

I have two trim pots with the outer legs in parallel to each other, and then have the middle pins going to the outer pins of the 16 mm pot. That then should "theoretically" change the low and high point of the main pot so you can't go out of the bounds set by the trim pots.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE - please edit your question and add a schematic. I think I know what you're asking, but it's not clear from you description. There's a built in schematic editor that will embed it into your question.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: From what you have drawn, having all 3 trim pots in series between the battery + and - terminals is the way to go. Your over complicating the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYSw3K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) The simple method. (b) Limiting interaction between the pots.*

The simple method.

- R1 and R3 set the voltage limits at each end of R3.
- The problem is that adjustment of R1 or R3 affects the total line resistance and so R1 and R3 interact. You would have to alternately adjust R1 and R3 until you got satisfactorily close to your desired setpoints.
- It is standard practice when using a potentiometer as a variable resistance (rheostat) to connect the wiper to the free end of the pot. This way if the wiper contact goes bad the circuit will still work - although with the wrong limit setpoint.

A more complex method.

- Here OA1 buffers R4 the max setpoint. Adjusting R6 will not affect the maximum setpoint.
- R6 is fed from the max setpoint so that it can be adjusted from zero to max. (If we had connected the top of it to V+ it would mean that you could adjust the minimum voltage higher than the maximum. This would make R5 work backwards so it's not desirable.)
- OA2 could be omitted and R5 connected to the wiper of R6 directly.
- Setup:

  - Set R5 to maximum. Adjust R4 to set maximum output.
  - Set R5 to minimum. Adjust R6 to set minimum output.

The op-amps would need to be able to swing their outputs to your V<sub>MAX</sub> and V<sub>MIN</sub> so they may be a complication you don't want at this stage in your electronics career.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDiADu.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Schematic version of OP's wiring diagram.*

What you have posted is a wiring diagram rather than a schematic. It is very difficult to determine how the circuit is supposed to work from that drawing and we use schematics so show the "scheme" of things.

Your circuit will work but will suffer the problem, mentioned in my answer, that the minimum voltage can be set higher than the maximum and then R2 will work backwards.

Comment: Sorry about not using schematics, didn't realize I shouldn't have used breadboard schematics. Yes, figure 1a works a lot better. The only issue I found when testing it just then is that because all the pots are 5kΩ, meaning when I turn R2 it changes from 5v to close to 0v then back to 5v at the other end. Maybe I should be using a 10Ω pot or something with a lot less resistance than the other two at 5kΩ.

Comment: Your post doesn't explain what you are driving with the potentiometers. Please edit to clarify. Please un-accept the answer until it's solved. This will also give time for others to post answers which may be better or different and give you other insights. Then pick the best.